# Minimal polynomial of degree 6

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, fields

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic not equal to $2$.

Assume $L/F$ is a field extension of degree $6$ with no intermediate subfields.

We know by a result due to Joubert (1867), later improved by H. Kraft (2006), that one can find $\alpha$ $\in L$ such that $L = F(\alpha)$ and $min_{\alpha , F}(X)$ = $X^6 + a_4X^4 + a_2X^2 + a_1X^1 + a_0$ where $a_i \in F^{*}$ and $a_1 = a_0 \neq 0$. This result concerns general separable field extensions of degree $6$ in characteristic $\neq 2$. My questions is whether this can be improved under the additional assumption that the Galois group corresponding to the normal closure of $L$ is either $S_6$ or $A_6$.

In particular, I am trying to reduce to the case where $min_{\alpha , F}(X)$ = $X^6 + a_1X^1 + a_0$ or $min_{\alpha , F}(X)$ = $X^6 + a_5X^5 + a_0$.

Any references to the literature outside of that mentioned above is appreciated!

Comment: First of all, the field extension does not change under the substitution $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_4)\mapsto (b^6 a_0,b^5a_1,b^4a_2,b^2a_4)$ for $b\in F^\ast$.  That means that there are really "$\leq 3$ moduli" of such field extensions.  In fact, there are precisely $3$ moduli, so you will never get away with fewer than $3$ undetermined coefficients.

Comment: What can be said along the same lines for extensions of degree 4 with no intermediate subfields?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403323.pdf Section 7 answers your question Gerry.